# Ingresar un icono fontawesome) en una celda con javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, font-awesome

Tengo una tabla de 5 columnas en html y casi 300 filas, la última columna **no tiene datos** , quiero **insertar un icono de fontawesome** y darle una acción mediante javascript, la cuál tome los datos de su fila y los ingrese en un textarea

Así esta el codigo:

```js
function consultar(){
  $("td.column-4").append('<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
};
```

```css
tr{
background-color:steelblue;
color:#fff;
}

td{
padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/141dcb7b72.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-12">
  <tr class="row-2 even" role="row">
    <td class="colunm-1">Firstname</td>
    <td class="colunm-2">Lastname</td> 
    <td class="colunm-3">Age</td>
    <td class="colunm-4">Agregar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-3 odd" role="row">
    <td class="colunm-1">Jill</td>
    <td class="colunm-2">Smith</td> 
    <td class="colunm-3">50</td>
    <td class="colunm-4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colunm-1">Eve</td>
    <td class="colunm-2">Jackson</td> 
    <td class="colunm-3">94</td>
    <td class="colunm-4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice algunas modificaciones para llegar a una posible solución:

- Modifiqué las clases de las celdas que son encabezados para no tratarlas de la misma manera que las celdas de datos
- Había un typo error, "colunm" > "column"
- La 4ta columna tiene text-align center para que el ícono quede alineado
- Para cada `td` con class `column-4` se agrega el plus icon como elemento hijo
- Para cada plus icon se agrega un onclick listener, donde se invoca una función que obtiene el `tr` mas cercano al ícono e itera sobre sus `td` (obtenidas mediante [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)), agregando sus valores a un `textarea`

```js
$("td.column-4").each(function(){
    $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
});
  
$(".fa-plus-circle").on("click", function(){
    let tr = $(this).closest("tr");     
    let tds = tr.find("td");             
    $(tds).each(function() {               
       $("#rowdata")[0].innerHTML += " "+  $(this).text();      
    });
    $("#rowdata")[0].innerHTML += "\n"
 });
```

```css
tr{
  background-color:steelblue;
  color:#fff;
}

td{
  padding:20px;
}

td.column-4{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/141dcb7b72.js"></script>
<table class="table-12">
  <tr class="row-2 even" role="row">
    <td class="headercolumn-1">Firstname</td>
    <td class="headercolumn-2">Lastname</td> 
    <td class="headercolumn-3">Age</td>
    <td class="headercolumn-4">Agregar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-3 odd" role="row">
    <td class="column-1">Jill</td>
    <td class="column-2">Smith</td> 
    <td class="column-3">50</td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="column-1">Eve</td>
    <td class="column-2">Jackson</td> 
    <td class="column-3">94</td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<textarea id="rowdata" rows="10" cols="50">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta , vaya que me es de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Posible error es que su clase es `colunm` y en `JS` lo hace con `column` por eso no añade el `icono` , además dicha función no se ejecuta al cargarse el DOM , quizá sería conveniente hacerlo.

```
$("td.colunm-4").append('<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
```

Se dio una respuesta con `Jquery` *(aunque cambiando la clase funcionaría)* , pero añadiré una opción para hacerlo solo con `JS` , sin `Jquery` , la explicación está dentro del código. Se empleó el método [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) para buscar la fila y [insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) para añadir el icono.

```js
var fourColumn = document.querySelectorAll('td.column-4'); //Obtenemos las columnas 
fourColumn.forEach(function(col){
    // Añadimos el icono a la columna
    col.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
});

//Obtenemos los iconos añadidos
var  icons = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-plus-circle');

icons.forEach(function(ic){
    // Añadimos el evento Click
    ic.addEventListener("click",function(){
        var row = this.closest('tr'); // Buscamos el Tr
        var columns = row.querySelectorAll('td'); // Todas las Columnas de la fila 
        var result = "";
        // Iteramos las columnas y añadimos su texto a la variable Result
        columns.forEach(function(col){ 
            result+= col.innerText + " ";
        });
        console.log(result); //Resultado
    });
});
```

```css
tr{
background-color:steelblue;
color:#fff;
}

td{
padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<table class="table-12" >
    <thead>
        <tr >
            <th class="column-1">Firstname</th>
            <th class="column-2">Lastname</th> 
            <th class="column-3">Age</th>
            <th class="column-4">Agregar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="row-1 odd" role="row">
            <td class="column-1">Jill</td>
            <td class="column-2">Smith</td> 
            <td class="column-3">50</td>
            <td class="column-4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-2 odd" role="row">
            <td class="column-1">Eve</td>
            <td class="column-2">Jackson</td> 
            <td class="column-3">94</td>
            <td class="column-4"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```